# Background synchronisation in android

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I'm new to Android development and currently trying to build an app where users can write messages to each other. However, I can't find anything on how to implement background synchronization so that notifications are displayed even when the app is closed. I have already read about services as they sounded promising but apparently they are not meant for this kind of tasks.

Online I only found examples with Google's Firebase, but I want to use my own servers.

I thought about it like this:
The client app connects to the server every n seconds and updates its message database. If a message is added that is marked as unread, a notification is triggered.

I don't know if I'm just googling the wrong things or have another thinking error but I can't find anything about it except some firebase examples.